# Sort a list of DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, jquery-ui-sortable, datarow

I have a `DataTable` that gets me `ID, Description, OptionID`

```
ID  Description OptionID
1   TEST        1
2   TEST2       1
2   TEST3       1
3   TEST4       2
```

Then based on a criteria I select OptionID 1 and add to list in order to remove duplicates:

```
 DataRow[] datarow = dt.Select("OptionID = 1");
 AddToList(lst, datarow);
```

Here is How I remove duplicates and and return a list of DataRow:

```
 private static List<DataRow> RemoveDuplicate(List<DataRow> drAllOptions)
    {
        List<DataRow> ldr = new List<DataRow>();
        List<int> safeGuard = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in drAllOptions)
        {
            if (!safeGuard.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"])))
            {
                ldr.Add(dr);
                safeGuard.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]));
            }
        }

        return ldr;
    }
```

And then assign the returned list of DataRow to `Repeater`, now I want to sort this list, tried using `lst.sort()` but I get an exception of `Failed to compare two elements in the array.` Any help would be appreciated.

PS. Am using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to say sort how to sort.
Take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

You have to do some kind of this

```
private static int MyComp(DataRow left, DataRow right)
{
    if (left["ID"] == right["ID"])
    {
       return 0;
    } 
    else
    {
       return 1;
    }
}

lst.Sort(MyComp)
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove Duplicates

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
   Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
   ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

   //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
   //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
   foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
   {
      if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
         duplicateList.Add(drow);
      else
         hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty); 
   }

   //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
   foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
      dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

   //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
      return dTable;
}
```

Here Links below

```
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4535-Remove-duplicate-records-from-table.aspx

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/94-remove-duplicate-rows-value-from-datatable.aspx
```

For remove duplicates in column

```
http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/02/removing-duplicate-records-from.html
```